# How can you align text in a tabular in the top left corner with listing

Tags: tables, listings, calc

I am creating a pseudo latex interface of a console GUI. I do not want to use screenshots of the GUI because I need the text to be able to go to the next page.

What I have right now is this:

```
\newcommand{\codein}[1]{\textcolor{codeblue}{\textbf{\texttt{In [#1]:}}}}
\newcommand{\codeout}[1]{\textcolor{codered}{\textbf{\texttt{Out[#1]:}}}}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\codein{1}}&\begin{lstlisting}[language=sage]
5+2
3
5\end{lstlisting}\\
\codeout{1}&{test}
\end{tabular}
```

Is there a way to consistently push my text to the top of my tabular?

Edit added definitions for `\codein` and `\codeout`. The language can be any language. My sage specifications are:

```
\definecolor{codegreen}{RGB}{45,161,129}
\definecolor{codedarkgreen}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{codered}{RGB}{189,74,86}
\definecolor{codepurple}{RGB}{171,51,254}
\definecolor{backcolour}{RGB}{247,247,247}
\definecolor{codeblue}{RGB}{80,106,192}

\lstdefinelanguage{sage}{
    morekeywords={in},
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codedarkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{codered},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    frame=single
} 
\lstset{literate=%
   *{0}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{codered!20!codegreen}9}}}1
    {=}{{{\color{codered!20!codepurple}=}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{codered!20!codepurple}/}}}1
    {-}{{{\color{codered!20!codepurple}-}}}1
    {+}{{{\color{codered!20!codepurple}+}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{codered!20!codepurple}*}}}1
    {^}{{{\color{codered!20!codepurple}^}}}1
}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952

Comment: How are `\codein` and `\codeout` defined?

Comment: @Ivan edited to add the custom definitions

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\definecolor{codered}{RGB}{189,74,86}
\definecolor{codeblue}{RGB}{80,106,192}
\newcommand{\codein}[1]{\textcolor{codeblue}{\textbf{\texttt{In [#1]:}}}}
\newcommand{\codeout}[1]{\textcolor{codered}{\textbf{\texttt{Out[#1]:}}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
\codein{1}&\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}\begin{lstlisting}
5+2
3
5
\end{lstlisting}\end{adjustbox}\\
\codeout{1}&{test}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out.

Using `\userpackage{calc}` you can just say `\raisebox{\baselineskip-10px}` where the `10px` is the height of your text.

Also note that I only got this to work for my case if I change `{ l l }` to `{ l p{3cm} }`

```
\begin{tabular}{ l p{3cm} }
\raisebox{\baselineskip-10px}{\codein{1}}&\begin{lstlisting}[language=sage]
5+2
3
5\end{lstlisting}\\
\codeout{1}&{test}
\end{tabular}
```

I cannot fully explain what the difference between `l` and `p` is.

Comment: This example code will result in an error message since the `p` type column is missing its mandatory width argument. Use something like `\begin{tabular}{ l p{3cm} }`  to get a properly compilable code.

Comment: Thank you @leandriis. I had mine with `p{14cm}` and didn't know it would error without it.